# React how to test function called in FileReader onload function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, jestjs, enzyme

I have the below code in a component. I want to test that onSubmit of the form, it calls the this.props.onUpload method in reader. 
How can I test that? 
My expect test is not working, I'm guessing it's because the this.props.onUpload is inside reader.onload function?

UploadForm.js

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var inputData = '';
    var file = this.state.file;
    if (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(file) {
            return function(e) {
                inputData = e.target.result;
                this.props.onUpload(inputData);
            };
        })(file).bind(this);
        reader.readAsText(file);            
    }

}

render() {
    return(
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label> Enter File: <br/>
                <input type="file" id="fileinput" onChange={this.handleChange}/>    
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn-upload" />
        </form>
    );
}
```

UploadForm.test.js

```
const mockOnUpload = jest.fn();
const file = new File([""], "filename");
const form = shallow(<UploadForm onUpload={mockOnUpload}/>);
const event = {
          preventDefault: jest.fn(),
          target: {files : [file]}
        };

describe('when clicking `upload-file` button', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      form.find('#fileinput').simulate('change', event);
      form.find('form').simulate('submit', event);
    });

    it('calls the handleSubmit CallBack', () => {
      expect(mockOnUpload).toHaveBeenCalledWith(input);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 5):

Super great start with the mock upload being passed in as a prop and creating a fake event!

I always like running into testing issues like these in my own work because it tells me I have a code smell: if it's not easy to test, it likely means it is harder to predict, harder to debug, harder to explain, &c.

I recommend breaking out your functions to more singled responsibility. As it stands, your `handleSubmit` is doing a bit more than just handling submit. It also adds an `onload` function to an instance of FileReader and calls `readAsText` on that instance.

Your [IIFE](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/an-introduction-to-iffes-immediately-invoked-function-expressions.html):

```
function(file) {
  return function(e) {
    inputData = e.target.result;
    this.props.onUpload(inputData);
  };
})(file).bind(this);
```

could be pulled out to an arrow function (taking care of `bind`) on the component:

```
readerOnLoad = file => (e) => {
  this.props.onUpload(e.target.result);
}
```

(Also, is `file` needed as an argument here? Doesn't appear to be used.)

Then `handleSubmit can interact with`readerOnLoad` like;

```
reader.onload = this.readOnLoad(file);
```

At this point, you can test that:

1. `handleSubmit` calls `readerOnLoad` with a file argument if it exists on state.
2. `readerOnLoad`, called with a file argument and then an event argument, calls `this.props.onLoad` with the event target `result` value.

If both of these tests pass, you can be confident that your code will work with real events, files, and FileReader instances.

It looks like you already understand how to pass in duck-type arguments (like `event`s) that match native/browser objects, so just put those together and enjoy the peace of mind of your nicely collaborating functions!

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out once I’m able to get to it